# Yii2: Is adding three models in single page & then validating separatly works in yii2

Tags: yii2

I am doing login module. I have done three separate models & views for password reset, signup & login.
as 
`passwordResetForm(), signupForm() & LoginForm()`

resp.

For all three models currently i have three separate views. If i add all the three forms in single view & pass all the three models to the view then at the time of submit, is it possible that if login info is filled & submitted then login model will validate & do its task without disturbing the other two models.

I am using java script's fade in & fade out effect to show the requested model out of the three above i mentioned.

Comment: Have 3 forms, submit with ajax each form to another action in the controller they should all work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a problem as long as your 3 different instances are not using the same variable name:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new \app\models\LoginForm();
    $signupModel = new \app\models\SignupForm();
    $passwordResetModel = new \app\models\PasswordResetForm()

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {       
        // login
    }    
    elseif ($signupModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {       
        // sign up 
    }   
    elseif ($passwordResetModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {       
        // reset password
    }   
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model, 
        'signupModel' => $signupModel, 
        'passwordResetModel' => $passwordResetModel,
    ]);
}
```